# Use Vaadin widgets in a pure client-side GWT application

Tags: gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

Following the Vaadin documentation, it seems from Vaadin 7 it is possible to use Vaadin widgets in a normal clientside GWT application:

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/widgets.vaadin.html

I could set this up so far following this wiki article:
https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20Vaadin%20in%20an%20existing%20GWT%20project

I get my project compiled now, but the standard GWT theme is used instead of a Vaadin theme, so the button background does not show up.

Since Vaadin themes are not GWT modules, how can I use them in a normal GWT application?

Comment: I would expect the normal "vaadin:compile-theme" output, e.g. `mytheme.css` to be sufficient. Have you tried that?

Comment: @AndreasKa: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?